# How to execute two threads Sequentially in a class

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on thread programming in java and i was stuck with a problem where i have to execute 2 threads one after another. Below is the code snippet that abstracts my problem in brief.

```
class A{
  //default execute method of this class
  String a="thread1";
  String b="thread2";
  public void execute(){
    if(a=="thread1"){
       CreateThread1 t1 = new CreateThread1(this);
       t1.call();
    }
    else if(b=="thread2") {
      CreateThread1 t2 = new CreateThread1(this);
       t2.call();
    }
  }//end of execute
  public void UpdateUI(){
    try{
      Display.getDefault.asyncExec(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            //ui update code here
        }
      });
    }
    catch(SWTException e){
    }
  }   
}

Class CreateThread1{
    private A object;
    public CreateThread1(A object){
      this.object=object
    }
    public void call(){
      Thread t = new Thread(this);
      t.start();
    }
    public void run(){ 
      //business logic here 
       object.UpdateUI();//updates UI 
    }
}
```

Here class A is User Interface class which shows progress of the Thread task, in the above code CreateThread1 starts and CreateThread2 also starts even if CreateThread1 is not killed, i wish CreateThread2 to be triggered only after CreateThread1 finishes its task completely.Is it possible? Any ideas?

Comment: The whole purpose of threads is concurrent execution.  Can you edit your question and explain _why_ you just can't call thread thread2 code from inside of thread1?

Comment: ..or, if for some weird reason, (and I can't think of one), you absolutely have to have a different thread to run the thread2 code, just 'call' it at the end of the thread1 run method.

Comment: Sequential execution is the default behavior.  You have to jump through hoops to get it to do something other than what raghav wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`FixedThreadPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) with a size of 1. This will guarantee sequential execution.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.submit(runnable1);
executor.submit(runnable2);
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //waits until both runnables have finished.
```

**EDIT**

ExecutorService uses synchonrized structures internally so you can safely assume that runnable1 will run before runnable2.

Comment: This will most likely work but I'm not sure the `submit` method guarantees execution order -- at least it doesn't mention it in the Javadocs.

Comment: That doesn't address the issue I don't think.  It just implies a memory barrier before each thread run, not the order of the run.  No worries, you are correct about the internal synchronous queue. I was just pointing it out for completeness.

Comment: @Gray Interesting that you think it doesn't. I would have thought that the happen-before guarantee means that there is some sort of synchronization which therefore prevents reordering of the 2 submit instructions.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time on this now academic discussion.  :-)  How I read the comment is that run1.run() includes all of the changes up to main.submit(run1) and the same for run2.  But that _doesn't_ mean that run2.run() won't necessarily execute _after_ run1.run().  There is memory synchronization but still might be race conditions on the order of execution.  Memory barrier != synchronization.

Comment: All that said, you initially mentioned that the internal synchronous queue would guarantee execution order.  I agree.  Again, sorry for the time waste.

Comment: @Gray no waste of time - I think it's an interesting academic discussion!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9972/discussion-between-gray-and-assylias)

Comment: @Gray after thinking about it, the guarantee made by ExecutorService is similar to that made by Thread ("A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread."). And I agree that this is not the good argument to justify that the 2 runnables will run in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

[`Thread#join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29), although I prefer to use the classes found within the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

Answer (score 1):

I read your question very quickly but what you probably need is join()
Have you looked at the Java Concurrency Tutorial ?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with a [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html). This is described in the docs for ThreadPoolExecutor.