# Using Thread.run() execute two threads simultaneously in an Enhanced loop

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public abstract class Multithread implements Runnable{
    static Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public  synchronized void run(){
            try {
                for(;;){
                    System.out.println("java");
                    t1.sleep(300);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception"+e);
            }
        }
    };
    static Thread t2 = new Thread(){
        public  synchronized void  run(){
            try{
                for(;;){
                    System.out.println("world");
                    t2.sleep(300);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception"+e);
            }
        }
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception "+e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("running");
    }
}
```

**Excepted O/P:**

```
java
world
java
world
java
world
.
.
.
.
```

**observed**
I tried using sleep() for the threads,they are  getting overlapped at some point of time like this-

```
java
java
world
java
world
world 
java 
..
```

**Expected**
i need these two threads to run in parallel and it should not get overlapped,either of the thread can be started. Any idea?

Comment: The usage of "synchronized" in your example is not right. You need to declare two class methods as synchronized instead of delegates to the Thread class.

Comment: what leads you to expect that if  you have read any java thread doc/ javadoc?

Answer (score 1):

Threads are not accurate in time. If they depend on each other, you have to manually synchronize, like : [How to execute two threads Sequentially in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110268/how-to-execute-two-threads-sequentially-in-a-class?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by having a counter, if the counter is 0 thread 1 executes, increments the counter and calls notyfyAll() on the counter, if the counter is 1 thread 1 calls wait() on the counter. And vice versa for thread 2.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute two threads in parallel, each one of them is executed independently by the underlying operating system. The task scheduler can decide when to execute which thread. This can result in uneven time distribution like you are experiencing.

One solution for this is to use shared [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)s to lock each thread until the other one has finished its task. Each thread would then take two semaphores, one for itself and one for the other thread. Both semaphores would start with one permit, so the first `release()` call doesn't block. The threads would then work like that (psudocode):

```
for (;;) {
    otherThreadSemaphore.acquire(); // blocks until the other thread called release()
    performWork();
    ownThreadSemaphore.release(); // allows the other thread to perform another iteration
}
```

Another would be to move the infinite loop out of the threads. In each iteration of the loop you spawn both threads, then use thread.yield() to wait until both threads are finished and then the loop starts again creating two new threads. But note that creating threads can be an expensive operation, so you should only do this when the threads do considerable amount of work in each iteration so that this doesn't matter much.